# Is is possible to defer a non abi action using a abi action?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, abi, deferred-transactions

I know we can defer a action in EOS, I invoke  a non-abi action from an abi action like this:

```
eosio::transaction txn{};
txn.actions.emplace_back(
    eosio::permission_level(owner, N(active)),
    N(account_one),
    N(non_abi_action),
    std::make_tuple(...args)
);
txn.delay_sec = delay;
txn.send(N(id), owner);
```

Is the above transaction correct? I tried but it didn't work. But, do we have some workaround to run this?

Comment: if it's not in the abi, then you can't communicate with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to call a non-ABI action in the way you want. Only something in the ABI can be called in a transaction, whether it is deferred or not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you couldn't execute non-abi action is that auto-generated action dispatcher doesn't contain action not marked with [[eosio::action]]. Write `apply` manually or use `EOSIO_DISPATCH` to dispatch your action correctly.